# When i try to build flutter web version it shows an error

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I try to build a web version for any project it shows this error

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: 
Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             30.0s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

even the default project gives the same error, but when I try to start debugging it works fine.

another problem is that when I build the apk version it shows this error but it builds the apk successfully.

```
Building with sound null safety
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          110.7s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (15.5MB).
```

I tried to redownload the flutter SDK but didn't work.

my `flutter doctor -v` result

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\Users\abduu\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (3 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\abduu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java      
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31605.320
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\abduu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.62

• No issues found!
```

What I have tried to do

- flutter clean
- flutter upgrade
- redownloading flutter SDK

Comment: does your project include `web` directory

Comment: yes, it does. and when I start debugging using chrome it works fine.

Comment: try with `flutter clean`  and does it happen only for this project?

Comment: I have tried flutter clean and tried to create a new project from scratch which contains nothing but the default project code and yet the same error.

Comment: try with flutter upgrade

Comment: I actually tried that too and if you read the question carefully you will see that I have also tried to redownload the flutter SDK but didn't work.

Comment: Yap, did you find any issue on `flutter doctor -v` and you can try again about upgrade instead of download.

Comment: no, and I have updated the question with the `flutter doctor -v` result and I have tried `flutter upgrade` and this is the result `Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`